# Windows RDP - Remote Control current users on Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, remote-desktop

Up to this day, I had a Windows Server 2008, and many users logging in remotely (around 10). Going to tasks manager, I can go to users, and if a user is logged in I can "Remote Control".

Now I need another PC to act as a terminal for those users, something related to adding more users and less load.

I gave my IT guy a Windows 10 PC to do it on, as I was requested, but after working on it for 4 hours and configuring everything, he said that there is no remote control option in Windows 10, but if I want I can install Windows 7.

- Does "Remote Control" exist on Windows 10 for RDP sessions?
- If not, does it really exist on Windows 7, and is reformatting my only option? I just don't really want to pay for another 4 hours of configuring stuff.

Note, I did see this option in technet, and it is listed only for windows server, [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771538(v=ws.11).aspx).

Comment: Do not 100% sure, but you can open RDP client with `/admin` option, so it will force the client to connect to the console session in stead of starting a new session. But it's only for Terminal Server connections, and the default Win desktop client will already connect to the console. It must be automatically.

Answer (score 0):

- No, it does not exist in Windows 10, but you may be able to use [rdpwrap](https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap), but I am not sure if it is against the EULA.
- [Yes, it does exist on Windows 7](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725700(v=ws.11).aspx), and reformatting is your only option, because you cannot downgrade to Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks. The link you sent says windows server, and will rdpwrap do what I need? I know I can use it for multiple sessions, but can I remote control?

Comment: You can log into a session and then remote control through task manager I think. I have not used rdpwrap before, I usually use a proper windows server license.